# Floating Elements and repositioning

Tags: html, css

I have 4 different divs assigned as: header1, header2, content1 and content2, each one floating to a specific side (left or right) as shown in the image1
[image: image1]

So far everything works fine:)! also Added a @media for the responsive result, so if the browser is smaller than 750px then everything become 100% wide.

And here's my problem, I'm trying to show elements like in this second image:[image: Image2]

But so far, Header 2 is showing just under header1 and I'm trying to locate first the content 1 before showing the header 2 with his respective content 2, could you help me to solve this? here's my actual jsfiddle and my code:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/KUBOGRAPHICS/msu684zu/)

HTML

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="header1">
       <h2 class="header1">
         Header 1
       </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="header2">
       <h2 class="header2">
         Header 2
       </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content1">
         content1
    </div>

    <div id="content2">
         content2
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you might be best off by grouping your header and content into one box (they are related, after all) and then aligning those boxes. And I'm pretty sure some people will suggest `flexbox`, which could work as well (but I never got swayed by it).

Comment: Your problem is the HTML structure. If you change the headers inside the contents your problem disappears automagically

Comment: lol problem solved @somethinghere

Comment: thanks pals! problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable for you, you can combine header with content.
See http://jsfiddle.net/pbrzt7er/

```
<div class='left container'>
    <div class='header'>
        Header left
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        Content left
    </div>
</div>
<div class='right container'>
    <div class='header'>
        Header right
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        Content right
    </div>
</div>
```